# Can I modify Bigcommerce CSS and/or add a banner based on Customer Group?

Tags: bigcommerce

In Bigcommerce, I'd like to revise the UX based on Customer Group login.

When an approved Dealer logs in to the Dealer group, we provide a wholesale discount. How can we use `%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%` to modify the template look & feel and provide a visual reminder that they're viewing the wholesale version?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this method, but what came to mind was adding the `%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%` as a class to the `<body>` or `<html>` tags of your theme and then use css to modify the page. You will have access to the customer group name as a css selector.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be pretty straightforward, posting the answer here in case anyone else is looking for something similar.

```
  $(document).ready(function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
        if ('%%GLOBAL_CustomerGroupName%%' == 'CUSTOMER-GROUP-NAME'){
            var fileref=document.createElement("link")
            fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
            fileref.setAttribute("href", "%%ASSET_Styles/custom.css%%")

        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
    });
```